# Variable appears to be lost when setting a property in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-3.2

I want create a property from a variable. The variables was created by calling a variable from a xpath extraction, then using a substring to then get the last 4 characters. The substring string value is saved to a variable, then set to a property.

When I run the script, the log.info(vars.get("lastcard")); returns the value of the variable. However it then fails to save to a property, because when that property is called(${__property(lastNum)} it will display - ${lastcard}

```
      import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
      import org.apache.commons.lang3;


      String tesTe = vars.get("card");
      String last4 = tesTe.substring(tesTe.length()-4,tesTe.length());
      vars.put("lastcard", String.valueOf(last4));
      log.info(vars.get("lastcard"));

     ${__setProperty(lastNum,${lastcard})};
```

Any ideas as to what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read [user manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) about scripting:

> ensure the script does not use any variable using ${varName}

You should use JSR223 variables `vars` and `props` to handle variables and properties. In your case change last line to:

```
 props.put("lastNum",  vars.get("lastcard"));
```

Also you can set variable in shorter way:

```
  vars.put("lastcard", vars.get("card").substring(tesTe.length()-4));
```

Comment: Your correct in that props.put should be used instead of setProperty, however I made another mistake in that setting a string to another string (string.valueOf was not required).

Comment: you are right, it's redundant, I added a shorter way to my answer

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 changes that need to be made to resolve the issues.

```
  import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
  import org.apache.commons.lang3;


  String tesTe = vars.get("card");
  String last4 = tesTe.substring(tesTe.length()-4,tesTe.length());
  vars.put("lastcard", last4);   //Already string therefore no need to use String.valueOf()
  log.info(vars.get("lastcard"));

 props.put("lastNum",vars.get("lastcard"));  //Setup to use props.put instead of set property
```